# Extracting YouTube Video's author using Python and YouTubeAPI

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

how do I get the author/username from an object using:

```
GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id=youtube_video_id_to_output)
```

I'm using Google's gdata.youtube.service Python library

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So because YouTube's API is based on GData, which is based on Atom, the 'author' object is an array with name objects, which can contain names, URLs, etc.

This is what you want:

```
>>> client = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
>>> video = client.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id='CoYBkXD0QeU')
>>> video.author[0].name.text
'GoogleDevelopers'
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanation Steph, it's all working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
foo = GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id=youtube_video_id_to_output)
foo.author
```

The [docs for YouTubeVideoEntry](http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pydocs/gdata.youtube.html#YouTubeVideoEntry) aren't great, but the `__init__` method seems to accept an author.

Comment: foo.author returns an atom object. I did dir() on it and there's no member that holds the author/username. It's wierd..